# CodeIgniter Grocery CRUD - doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

I have a page with accounts and I want to add a grocery CRUD table where you can add up your transactions. I'm a newbie and I have to do this for my uni. I'm having a database table with data(date), category_id(int), tranz_type(char5), suma(decimal) and descriere(longtext).

I want to make the grocery CRUD with 5 columns (date, transaction type, category, describe and sum) and a button where you can add your new transaction.

Account.php - controller. I need a new function I think.

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');    

    class Conturi extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->database();
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->library('grocery_crud');
        }    
        public function _conturi_output($output = null){
          $this->load->view('conturi',$output);
        }    
        public function index(){
          $this->_conturi_output( (object) array('output' => '', 'js_files' => array(), 'css_files' => array()));
        }
```

Maybe you can help me with the view file and the controller. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't know how I can see it in the view file and I haven't got any ideea about grocery CRUD.